# CSS width is automatically maximum in one row

Tags: css

I have 2 divs in a row (with inline-blocks). One of them has a fixed width and the other one is supposed to automatically fill the left space. How can I do that?

Comment: help us help you, show the code you have already written with those two `<div>`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite solution is to use padding on the container block and absolute position on the fixed with object:

```
.wrapper {
  padding-left: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.stay {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

  /* for demo */
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.fit {
  width: 100%;

  /* for demo */
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="stay"></div>
  <div class="fit"></div>
</div>
```